# Having issue with base constructors used in derived class

Tags: c++

I'm running a code in which I'm using two base classes and deriving a derived class from them. I'm calling both of their constructors in the Derived class and I'm giving arguments in main. When I compile it doesn't give me any kind of error. But when I try to run the program it doesn't run, I'm really confused!
Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
class Date 
{
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
public:

      Date(int d,int m,int y)
      {
        day=d;
        month=m;
        year=y;
      }

        void display()
        {
            cout<<endl<<day<<"\\"<<month<<"\\"<<year<<endl;
        }
        void set()
        {
            cout<<"Enter day :";
            cin>>day;
            cout<<"Enter month :";
            cin>>month;
            cout<<"Enter year :";
            cin>>year;
        }
                // sets the date members
    };

class Time 
{
        int hour;
        int minute;
        int second;
public:

        Time(int h,int min,int s)
        {
            hour=h;
            minute=min;
            second=s;
        }


        void display()  // displays the time
        {
            cout<<endl<<hour<<":"<<minute<<":"<<second<<endl;
        }
        void set()
        {
            cout<<"Enter hour :";
            cin>>hour;
            cout<<"Enter minute :";
            cin>>minute;
            cout<<"Enter seconds :";
            cin>>second;
        }
                // sets the time members
    };

class DateAndTime : public Date, public Time 
{
        int digital;
public:

    DateAndTime(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e,int f):
    Date(a,b,c),Time(d,e,f)
    {
    }


    void set()
    {
        Date:set();
        Time:set();
    }
    void display()
      {
        Date:display();
        Time:display();
      }
            // prints date and time
    };
int main()
{
  DateAndTime Watch(17,02,1999,03,36,56);
  Watch.display();
  Watch.set();
  Watch.display();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post what the actual error is.

Comment: Did you mean to write `Time::set();` You're using one colon when you should be using two all over the place.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this compiles without errors. How do you compile? Can you provide the commandline and whatever output occurs?
 Maybe add some nitpicking switches like `-Wall`. Can you use the same method of compiling on a trivial program? E.g. a typical "Hello World".

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function

```
void set()
{
    Date:set();
    Time:set();
}
```

is wrong but the compiler does not complain because it treats `Date:` and `Time:` as labels. If you separate the labels and the function calls, the function is:

```
void set()
{
    Date:   // Unused label.
       set();  // Calls the function again, leading to infinite recursion
               // and stack overflow.
    Time:  // Unused label.
       set();  // The function never gets here.
}
```

You need to use:

```
void set()
{
    Date::set();
    Time::set();
}
```

You need to update `display` similarly. Use:

```
void display()
{
   Date::display();
   Time::display();
}
```

Comment: @Zaina please, if this answer suit your needs, consider accepting the answer.